# How to read json encoded value using php?

Tags: php, json

I have a variable in PHP, named as $partialSegments. I want to iterate through it and perform actions when I strike `operator` or `rOperandValue`, etc. I receive it in a function call, so while making the

```
function named(say):
 public function convertJsCode($partialSegments){
//logic
}
```

I am struggling with the *logic*

```
"segments":{"type":"custom","partialSegments":[{"type":"7","operator":11,"rOperandValue":["windows xp"],"prevLogicalOperator":null},{"type":"8","operator":11,"rOperandValue":["other"],"prevLogicalOperator":"AND"}]}}
```

Comment: Where You get this. Add Some Description

Comment: json_decode should help you to transform it to arrays/objects.

Comment: @TarangP sorry, I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @jh1711 Okay I will have a look
However, is there a chance that this data can be stored in a PHP variable?
If yes, how would I iterate through it?

Comment: title should be: How to read json encoded value using php?
 and you should add json tag. Your title does not make sense.

Comment: *"How to read json encoded value using php?"* -- PHP provides the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function for this purpose. Pass `TRUE` as its second argument to get back associative arrays instead of objects; they are easier to handle.

Comment: @axiac 
Thanks, I got it working!

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan 
I edited it long back, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function in php

```
  <?php

$json = '{"segments":{"type":"custom","partialSegments":[{"type":"7","operator":11,"rOperandValue":["windows xp"],"prevLogicalOperator":null},{"type":"8","operator":11,"rOperandValue":["other"],"prevLogicalOperator":"AND"}]}}';

$parsed = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($parsed["segments"]["partialSegments"] as $val) {


    $operator = $val["operator"]; // operator value 
    $rOperandValue = $val["rOperandValue"][0]; // rOperandValue value 

}

?>
```

Comment: And how can I iterate through it?
I have used the function json_decode($partialSegments, true)
Now when I print the decoded value, this is the answer:
I am getting the same json printed while print_r(), my doubt is how can i iterate through it?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/users/6023296/aman-kumar](Aman Kumar) 
I got what you are saying. Sorry for not getting it at first and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** convert json encoded data into php array using `json_decode();` function. This function receive two arguments: first one is: json_encoded data which should be decoded and 2nd one is: `boolean(TRUE or FALSE)`. pass second argument as TRUE to convert the json concoded values as php array, if you pass false it will return php object.

**Step2:** iterate php array and set the logic like a charm.

```
<?php

$json = '{"segments":{"type":"custom","partialSegments":[{"type":"7","operator":11,"rOperandValue":["windows xp"],"prevLogicalOperator":null},{"type":"8","operator":11,"rOperandValue":["other"],"prevLogicalOperator":"AND"}]}}';

$parsed = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($parsed as $single){
  $segments = $single['partialSegments'];
  //print_r($single);

  foreach($segments as $segment){
      echo 'operator:'. $segment['operator'].'<br>';
            print_r($segment['rOperandValue']);
      // put your logic based on 'operator' or 'rOperandValue'
    }

}

?>
```

**Suggestion:**  Don't use hard code index to work with an array like: `$segment['rOperandValue'][0]`. array could be empty. i.e: if you want to do anything when a value is found in `$segment['rOperandValue'] use in_array()`.

Comment: Yeah, I avoided using the hard coded value. 
Thank you!